# Вывод содержимого файла в richTextBox

Tags: c#

вывожу содержимое файла txt в richtextbox , но русские символы не правильно оторабажаются.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files | *.txt";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);       
        }
```

Comment: `но русские символы не правильно оторабажаются` но вы не покажете этого, верно? Хрустальный шар говорит, что у вас проблема где то в кодировках. Пересохраните файл в UTF-16 и попробуйте снова.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался)

Comment: @tym32167 а мне шар говорит, что вопрос хочет закрыться, как неактуальный.